# How to autostart windows services in C#

Tags: c#, service, windows-services

I already made a windows service that should autostart when Windows starts up, but for some reason It does not work. I used the code below:

```
private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
        {
            sc.Start();
        }
    }
```

After install the service using InstallUtil.exe it starts automatically, but if I make a restart it does not start even when the configuration in the Service Manager is "Automatic".

I already tried changing for "Automatic (Delayed Start) " but nothing changed.

I will appreciate some advice.

Sorry for my poor english, I'm not a native.

Thanks

Comment: Follow this link this may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411044/windows-service-doesnt-start-automatically

Comment: In think you want to run  your project as administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace curUsers
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        var processInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
        var serviceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();

        //set the privileges
        processInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;

        serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "curUsers";
        serviceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;

        //must be the same as what was set in Program's constructor
        serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "curUsers";

        this.Installers.Add(processInstaller);
        this.Installers.Add(serviceInstaller);
    }

    private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void serviceProcessInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Just try this, all of my windows services are developed in the same way. this one also works well.

Answer (score 0):

I built several windows services a while back. Maybe this will help solve your issue

```
// serviceInstaller1
 // 
 this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "whoisthere";
 this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
 this.serviceInstaller1.AfterInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(this.serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall);
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. The service works fine after installation, but not after reboot the system. It seems like Windows is unable to start it up by it self.